# Сохранить значение this для onlick?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице имеется глобальная переменная `var btnActive;`
Для ссылки повешано событие onlick:

```
onclick="return ProfileEditor.saveContacts(this)"
```

Далее рассмотрим метод **saveContacts**:

```
saveContacts: function(btn){
        this.serializeForm(btn);
        this.sendAjax(formData);
        return false;
    },
```

И метод **serializeForm**:

```
serializeForm: function(th){
        var btnActive = th;
    },
```

И наконец, где я пытаюсь получить исходное значение **this** от события клик:

```
sendAjax: function (param){
var savedBtn = btnActive; // Переменная глобальная
}
```

Но это не сработало. Как можно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), я вам как-то раз уже отвечал на вопрос и убедительно просил, прочитайте про такое понятие, как **[var](http://javascript.ru/var)**, и как его правильно использовать, а также что такое область видимости переменной.

```
serializeForm: function(th){
    var btnActive = th;
},
```

Здесь btnActive обозначена как локальная переменная.

Comment: Видимо, ваш предыдущий урок не усвоил... Буду внимательней! Спасибо.